# Dynamic array of pointers to structs- how to pass to funcs?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to figure out how should I get some code done so I will send a dynamic array of pointers to structs to functions and will be able to free all memory at the end of the program.

```
Void main()
{
Some_struct **array;
array = (Some_struct**)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct));
}
```

Now should my function be like:

```
Void My_func(Some_struct** array)
{ //Code}
```

Or should it be like:

```
Void My_func(Some_struct*** array)
    { //Code}
```

I would like some explanation pls :)

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using that reproduces whatever problem you are having (e.g.,1-3 lines of actual use instead of `// Code` + the calling code and definitions of any required variables). (In this case I suspect that if you do that, the compiler errors _when you test that code before posting it here_, or lack thereof, will show you which is the correct way.)

Comment: `sizeof(struct)` is invalid C code.  Suggest `array = malloc(sizeof *array * 10);`  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: regarding: `Void` there is no such modifier in C.  Perhaps you meant: `void` (all lower case) Regarding: `Void main()`  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`  they are: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  and  `int main( void )`   Notice that both signatures use a return type of `int`

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you intend to do with `array` within the function. If you intend to, for example, reallocate it, then define your function's parameter with an extra level of pointer (`***`).

Comment: Yes I want to reallocate my array, then it seems that the second option is correct. 
And I should send the array to the function like this:
My_func(&array)